# Problemas na hora de imprimir o arquivo de números ordenados

Tags: c, classificação

Galera, boa noite, estou tendo um problema com esse algoritmo, peço que me iluminem com seu conhecimento.
Peço desculpas antecipadas se for difícil de entender o código, ainda estou no 2º período.

> O **objetivo** do algoritmo é:

Gerar um vetor com n números randômicos e os salvar em um arquivo, ordenar esses números de acordo com a opção dada em um procedimento que pergunta o tipo de ordenação desejada, e finalmente a impressão dos números do vetor em outro arquivo, só que dessa vez devidamente ordenados.

> O **problema** é:

Na hora de imprimir os arquivos com números ordenados, onde um arquivo deveria conter os números randômicos e o outro arquivo os mesmos números, só que ordenados, **mas** eles não estão ordenando.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <locale.h>

#define TAM 5000

void opcoes();
void CV(int *n);                                            //Criar vetor                                                 
void OV(int *n, int opcao, int ini, int fim);               //Ordenar vetor         
int PV(int *n, int ini, int fim);                           //Particionar vetor         
void IV(int *n);                                            //Imprimir vetor            

int main(){
    srand(time(0));
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Portuguese");

    int t, i, n[TAM], ini=i, fim=TAM-1;

    opcoes();
    t=clock();
    CV(n);
    OV(n,0,ini,fim);
    IV(n);
    t=clock()-t;

    printf("\nTempo de processamento: %0.3f segundos.\n",(float)(t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    return 0;
}
```

> Procedimento para selecionar um determinado tipo de ordenação:

```
void opcoes(){
    int opcao;

    do{
    printf("\nDigite a opção do algoritmo de ordenação: \n\n1 - BUBBLE SORT\n2 - INSERTION SORT\n3 - SELECTION SORT\n4 - QUICK SORT\n\n");
    scanf("%d",&opcao);
    }while((opcao<1)||(opcao>4));
}
```

> Procedimento para criar o vetor:

```
 void CV(int *n){
    int i; FILE *A;

    A=fopen("A.txt","r");
    if(A==NULL){
        printf("\n\"A.txt\" inexistente, criando arquivo.\n");
        fclose(A);

            A=fopen("A.txt","w");
            for(i=0;i<TAM;i++){
                n[i]=rand()%10000+1;
                //printf("%d ",n[i]);
                fprintf(A,"%d ",n[i]);
            }
    fclose(A);
    }
fclose(A);
}
```

> Procedimento para ordenar o vetor, de acordo com a opção dada no procedimento **opcoes**:

```
void OV(int *n, int opcao, int ini, int fim){
    int i, j, pivo, sel, aux;

    switch(opcao){

        case 1:                                     //bubble sort
            for(i=0;i<TAM;i++){
                for(j=0;j<TAM-1;j++){
                    if(n[j]<n[j+1]){
                        aux=n[j];
                        n[j]=n[j+1];
                        n[j+1]=aux;
                    }
                }
            }
        break;

        case 2:                                     //insertion sort
            for(i=1;i<TAM;i++){
                aux=n[i];
                for(j=i-1;(j>=0)&&(aux>n[j]);j--){
                    n[j+1]=n[j];
                }
                n[j+1]=aux;
            }
        break;

        case 3:                                     //selection sort
            for(i=0;i<TAM-1;i++){
                sel=i;
                for(j=i+1;j<TAM;j++){
                    if(n[j]<n[sel]){
                    sel=j;
                    }
                }
                if(i!=sel){
                    aux=n[i];
                    n[i]=n[sel];
                    n[sel]=aux;
                }
            }
        break;

        case 4:                                     //quick sort
            if(ini<fim){
                pivo=PV(n,ini,fim);
                OV(n, opcao, ini, pivo-1);
                OV(n, opcao, pivo+1,fim);
            }
        break;  
    }
}
```

> Função que particiona o vetor no caso de um **bubble sort**:

```
int PV(int *n, int ini, int fim){
    int pivo=n[ini], i=ini,  j, aux;

    for(j=ini+1;j<=fim;j++){
        if(n[j]>=pivo){
            i++;
            aux=n[i];
            n[i]=n[j];
            n[j]=aux;
        }
    }
    aux=n[i];
    n[i]=n[ini];
    n[ini]=aux;

    return i;
}
```

> Procedimento para imprimir o vetor (em tese ordenado), em outro arquivo.

```
void IV(int *n){
    int i; FILE *OA;

    OA=fopen("Ordenado-A.txt","r");
    if(OA==NULL){
        printf("\n\"Ordenado-A.txt\" inexistente, criando arquivo.\n");
        fclose(OA);

        OA=fopen("Ordenado-A.txt","w");
        for(i=0;i<TAM;i++){
            fprintf(OA,"%d ",n[i]);
            //printf("%d ",n[i]);
        }
        fclose(OA);
    }
    fclose(OA);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Na chamada a função OV, você passa zero no segundo argumento.

```
int main(){
srand(time(0));
setlocale(LC_ALL,"Portuguese");

int t, i, n[TAM], ini=i, fim=TAM-1;

opcoes();
t=clock();
CV(n);
OV(n,0,ini,fim);
IV(n);
t=clock()-t;

printf("\nTempo de processamento: %0.3f segundos.\n",(float)(t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
return 0;
}
```

Esse valor é processado pela switch dentro da função e não opera nenhuma ação, pois, o valor zero não esta incluido em nenhum dos cases.

O que pode ser feito é o seguinte:

```
int main(){
srand(time(NULL));
setlocale(LC_ALL,"Portuguese");

int t, i, n[TAM], ini=i, fim=TAM-1;

int opcao = opcoes();
t=clock();
CV(n);
OV(n,opcao,ini,fim);
IV(n);
t=clock()-t;

printf("\nTempo de processamento: %0.3f segundos.\n",(float)(t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Funcionou, agora só falta colocar o vetor pra ficar ordenado.